# Struggling with the texture for Wagashi (a Japanese dessert)

Tags: texturing, materials

I am trying to reproduce Wagashi (a kind of Japanese dessert) in a 3D scene. It is called Hanabi and I used this video as my reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXJzjPtl9Sg
[image]

A model with texturing is already been built but there are some problems.
[image][image]
It is lacking transparency although I have tried different parameters like transparent and subsurface scattering (SSS). I should say it
looks like a plastic ball more than food. How to improve my model and create a realistic Wagashi?

Here are the model files:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fsofofw06kzeisy/AAAucpV6lSvV-Hi8L-0fM651a?dl=0

Thank you!:D

Comment: The SSS is the most obvious difference, try to increase the radius, play around with the colors and the overall amount of SSS. Also the scale of your object is important when you use SSS, check if your wagashi size is acurate to the reference wagashi.

Comment: Hi :). Your hanabi is 4 meters wide. Scale your scene to 0,001 size, apply scale and SSS will have much more realistic effect.

Comment: I almost forget the size... Thank you for answering! I will try what you have mention. :D

Comment: also, in addition to SSS, you should give it a colored noise texture